# How to add subdomain in google cloud DNS?

Tags: django, nginx, google-cloud-platform, web-hosting, google-cloud-dns

I have a compute engine running in google cloud. I linked this compute engine with a domain like example.com but I want to host another web apllication on the same compute engine and access it via subdomain like app.example.com, so can anyone tell me how I can link or add a new subdomain to same compute engine.

Comment: This question is off-topic on Stack Overflow because it is not about programming.  In the future similar questions should be asked elsewhere.  Questions about managing your server can be asked at [sf] and questions about managing your website can be asked at [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I logged in on domain provider site with my domain and created a subdomain, then on google cloud I created a new record with a subdomain like app.example.com with type A and 300 sec TTL and added the IP address of the compute engine. this solves my query.